How to configure a frontend's Alchemy provider with JWTs?
I've gone through the Alchemy JWT Docs, and this has left me confused since they need to be short-lived. Currently in development, I'm simply using an Alchemy API key as an environment variable, but this is not recommended for production.
I believe I can just swap the API key out for a JWT token? But how does this work in practice if it has to be updated for instance every hour? How is this accomplished? I'm having trouble finding anything about this on Alchemy or even Google. What are the best practices? Is there a resource for these things?
TLDR: How should JWT tokens for Alchemy API calls be updated in production?

From what I get from your question you're specifically looking for some way to handle the JWT in your frontend before it expires.
What you need to be aware of that the creation of the JWT has to happen on the backend side, and you then share this with your frontend.
For that you need to run you own server/backend and you need to handle generating a key pair as described in this section and then generate the token as described in this part of the docs.
handling frontend
If you read the docs you can already read what a JWT contains, the second part is the payload. Decoding this gives you JSON where you can access the expiriation time exp.
example code to decode JWT
function decodeJWT(token) {
  const payloadBase64 = token.split('.')[1];
  const decodedPayload = JSON.parse(atob(payloadBase64));
  return decodedPayload;
}

once you decoded it you can periodically check when the token is expiring. The exp is in Unix timestamp format, you can compare with the current time f.e. with Date.now() (returns milliseconds, convert to seconds).
example to decode
// current time in sec
const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); 
// decode token
const decodedToken = decodeJWT(jwtToken);
// get expiration time  
const expiresAt = decodedToken.exp;        
// time left in seconds
const timeUntilExpiration = expiresAt - now; 

Depending on how your tokens expire, you can handle some refreshing logic.
example function  to handle refresh
async function refreshTokenIfNeeded(token) {
  const decodedToken = decodeJWT(token);
  const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Current time in seconds

  // If the token is expiring in less than 5 minutes (300 seconds), refresh it
  if (decodedToken.exp - now < 300) {
    console.log("Token is about to expire. Refreshing...");

    // fetch new token from your backend
    const response = await fetch('/get-alchemy-token');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.token;
  }
  // if not expiring, return the same token
  return token; 
}

check expiration time regularly
setInterval(async () => {
  jwtToken = await refreshTokenIfNeeded(jwtToken);
  // Update the Alchemy provider with the new token if it was refreshed
  alchemyProvider = new Alchemy({ apiKey: jwtToken });
}, 60000); // Check every minute

if you use the alchemy SDK you can just re-initialize.
handling refresh
async function updateAlchemyProvider(newToken) {
  alchemyProvider = new Alchemy({
    apiKey: newToken
  });
}

you can also do this regularly
setInterval(async () => {
  jwtToken = await refreshTokenIfNeeded(jwtToken);

  updateAlchemyProvider(jwtToken); 
}, 60000); // check every minute

Rest depends on your apps logic, how long you want to keep the tokens valid, or any other app requirements and code handling you have.
you could consider some code handling if the token handling fails
refresh on expired
try {
  // make an alchemy API call
  const result = await alchemyProvider.getSomeData();
} catch (error) {
  if (error.message === "JWT expired") {
    // token has expired so get a new one and retry
    jwtToken = await refreshTokenIfNeeded(jwtToken);
    updateAlchemyProvider(jwtToken);

    // retry the request with new token
    const result = await alchemyProvider.getSomeData();
  }
}

Depending how your project is setup you can customize this logic to your needs and requirements.
